# Querying from Parse Classes

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to query the user's from _User class, which I have managed successfully. But what I am trying to do now where I'm having a bit of difficulty, is query another class, Posts, and download the images that match the users downloaded from the first query?!

So I am just trying to assign the images from the Posts class to the correct users from the _User class...It sounds very simple, but it driving me mad!!

Here's my code for the query, I know it's probably not the best way but I'm newish to Swift! But I'm willing to try any tips or recommendations if you have any!

```
let userQuery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
userQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({
    (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
    if error == nil {
        self.profilePicArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.fullnameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

        for an object in objects! {
            self.profilePicArray.append(object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
            self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)
            self.fullnameArray.append(object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String)
            self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)
        }

        let imageQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
        imageQuery.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.usernameArray)
        imageQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.lastPicArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for an object in objects! {
                    self.lastPicArray.append(object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                }
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
    } else {
        print(error!.localizedDescription)
    }
})
```

**The result I am getting at the moment is that: all user's download and also all the posts, but the images are just assigned randomly to each user or all the posts appear for each single user!**

Thanks in advance.

**New Query**

```
 func uu() {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.includeKey("latestImage")
    query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (object:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if error == nil {

            for object in object! {


                if (object.objectForKey("latestImage") != nil)
                {

                    self.lastPicArray.append(object.objectForKey("latestImage")!.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
                    self.profilePicArray.append(object.valueForKey("profilePicture") as! PFFile)
                    self.fullnameArray.append(object.valueForKey("firstname") as! String)
                    self.usernameArr.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)

                }

                }

            self.collectionView.reloadData()


            print(self.usernameArr)
            print(self.lastPicArray)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just one query, by using the includeKey function of Parse Queries

[Parse Queries](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-relational-queries)

Take your 2nd query, and add something like this:

```
let imageQuery = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
imageQuery.whereKey("username", containedIn: self.usernameArray)
imageQuery.includeKey("fieldNameOfUserPointer")
```

Just change the 'fieldNameOfUserPointer' to the field name that references your _User object in the Posts entity.

Comment: Hi ben thanks for your answer. So I should get rid of the first query for the _User class, and just leave the imageQuery but use a pointer and then call includKey function?

Comment: Yep.  That would be much better.

Comment: Hey, if you check the new query I added above you'll see how I've done it. So "latesImage" is a pointer to the Posts class and in its rows it has the object Id for the latest post by each user. But what I'm still trying to do is, get into the posts class from the _User class and get the latest 3 images, not just 1.. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sure - you've done it backwards to how I suggested.  You're new query is querying the _Users table and including the Post....

My suggestion was to query the Post table and include the _User - see my code example above.

Do you have a pointer in your Posts table that points back to the User? If so, what's it called?

Comment: Ok. I don't have a pointer but I'll create one, but how would I display just the images belonging to each user on a different cell?

Comment: There are many different ways, personally I'd look to use a dictionary with the userId as they key, and array of images as the value.  You're getting a bit off topic now ;)